# Permission for Figure Reuse

Tags: vision

I was wondering how I can go about gaining permission for reuse of a figure in this post. I was hoping to reuse the image that is exemplifying the cross section of the retina. If anyone know please let me know I appreciate the help!

Comment: This question is off-topic here, because it is not about biology. It is on-topic in [academia.stackexchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). I can migrate it if you want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about figure reuse and not biology.